# Flutter: How to add additional values in the subtitled from additional objects

Tags: flutter, dart

How to add additional values in the subtitled from additional objects

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<List<Photo>> fetchPhotos(http.Client client) async {
  final response =
  await client.get('https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/market/batch?symbols=SLVO,GLDI,SPFF,CNPF,MONY&types=quote,**stats**&token=');

  // Use the compute function to run parsePhotos in a separate isolate.
  return compute(parsePhotos, response.body);
}

// A function that converts a response body into a List<Photo>.
List<Photo> parsePhotos(String responseBody) {
  //final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  //return parsed.map<Photo>((json) => Photo.fromJson(json)).toList();

  dynamic Obj = json.decode(responseBody);
  print(Obj.length);
  List<Photo> photoList = [];
  Obj.forEach((k, v,y) => photoList.add(Photo(k,v,y)));

  return photoList;
}

class Photo {
  String symbol;
 dynamic data;
  dynamic stats;
  Photo(this.symbol ,this.data, this.stats);
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appTitle = 'Isolate Demo';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Photo>>(
        future: fetchPhotos(http.Client()),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

          return snapshot.hasData
              ? PhotosList(photos: snapshot.data)
              : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PhotosList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Photo> photos;

  PhotosList({Key key, this.photos}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
      ),
      itemCount: photos.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.album),
          subtitle: Column(
            children: [
             // Text( ' ${photos[index].stats["stats"]["dividendYield"]["companyName"]}'),
            //  Text( ' ${photos[index].data["quote"]["iexRealtimePrice"]}' ' ${photos[index].stats["stats"]["dividendYield"]["companyName"]}'),
              Text( ' ${photos[index].data["quote"]["iexRealtimePrice"]}'),
              Text ( ' ${photos[index].stats["stats"]["dividendYield"]}'),
            ],
          ),
         //title: Text(photos[index].symbol),
         //subtitle: Text( ' ${photos[index].stats["stats"]["dividendYield"]["companyName"]}'),
          //subtitle: Text( ' ${photos[index].data["quote"]["iexRealtimePrice"]}' ' ${photos[index].stats["stats"]["dividendYield"]["companyName"]}'),
       // subtitle: Text( ' ${photos[index].data["quote"]["iexRealtimePrice"]}'),
         // subtitle: Text ( ' ${photos[index].stats["stats"]["dividendYield"]}'),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Print/display more values (More than 1) in the subtitled.

```
          leading: Icon(Icons.album),
          title: Text(photos[index].symbol),
         subtitle: Text( ' ${photos[index].stats["stats"]["dividendYield"]["companyName"]}'),
          //subtitle: Text( ' ${photos[index].data["quote"]["iexRealtimePrice"]}' ' ${photos[index].stats["stats"]["dividendYield"]["companyName"]}'),
          //subtitle: Text( ' ${photos[index].data["quote"]["stats"]["iexRealtimePrice"]}'),
         // subtitle: Text ( ' ${photos[index].stats["stats"]["dividendYield"]}'),
        );
```

Json

> > {"SLVO":{**"stats"**:{"week52change":0.047256,"week52high":7.48,"week52low":6.23,"marketcap":null,"employees":null,"day200MovingAvg":6.88,"day50MovingAvg":7.13,"float":null,"avg10Volume":7454.8,"avg30Volume":7927.83,"ttmEPS":null,"ttmDividendRate":null,"companyName":"Credit Suisse X-Links Silver Shares Covered Call ETN","sharesOutstanding":0,"maxChangePercent":58.7391,"year5ChangePercent":-0.4128,"year2ChangePercent":-0.1369,"year1ChangePercent":0.047256,"ytdChangePercent":-0.005789,"month6ChangePercent":0.074445,"month3ChangePercent":-0.035112,"month1ChangePercent":-0.025532,"day30ChangePercent":-0.035112,"day5ChangePercent":-0.007225,"nextDividendDate":null,"dividendYield":null,"nextEarningsDate":null,"exDividendDate":null,"peRatio":null,"beta":-0.06347545711182472},**"quote"**:{"symbol":"SLVO","companyName":"Credit Suisse X-Links Silver Shares Covered Call ETN","primaryExchange":"NASDAQ","calculationPrice":"close","open":6.89,"openTime":1574346600589,"close":6.88,"closeTime":1574370000242,"high":6.9,"low":6.87,"latestPrice":6.88,"latestSource":"Close","latestTime":"November 21,

**Added:**
&types=**stats**,quote&token

[image]

**In addition to price in the subtitled I would like for example:**

> week52change":0.047256 or marketcap":null

[image: Example]

Comment: @chunhunghan Just added "stats",quote&token to the api json url. and would like to print the additional value into the subtitle were the price is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Column`, perhaps?

```
  leading: Icon(Icons.album),
  title: Text(photos[index].symbol),
  subtitle: Column(
    children: [
      Text( ' ${photos[index].stats["stats"]["dividendYield"]["companyName"]}'),
      Text( ' ${photos[index].data["quote"]["iexRealtimePrice"]}' ' ${photos[index].stats["stats"]["dividendYield"]["companyName"]}'),
      Text( ' ${photos[index].data["quote"]["stats"]["iexRealtimePrice"]}'),
      Text ( ' ${photos[index].stats["stats"]["dividendYield"]}'),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: I/flutter (28902): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (28902): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building:
I/flutter (28902): The method '[]' was called on null.
I/flutter (28902): Receiver: null
I/flutter (28902): Tried calling: []("stats")

Comment: @DevEd Looks like `photos[index].stats` is null then. You're going to have to figure out why that is.

Comment: @ Abion47 thanks for providing the original answer. I added the full code. can you take a look let me know why would it be empty if the json code has data.